# dividir en dos un arreglo de NodeList

Tags: javascript, array, dom

quiero poder dividir un arreglo de nodeList en dos, tengo mi arreglo de esta forma:

```
arreglo = [ div1, div2, div3, div4, div5, div6, div7, div8, div9, div10];
```

y quiero que quede asi:

```
arr1 = [div1, div2, div3, div4, div5];
arr2 = [div6, div7, div8, div9, div10];
```

el codigo que estoy utilizando es este:

```
let mitadArr1 = Array.prototype.slice.call(5, arreglo)
let mitadArr2 = Array.prototype.slice.call(arreglo, 5),
```

pero solo me genera el segundo arreglo arreglo.

les agradezco por leerme.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El uso del método `call()` es el siguiente:

```
fun.call(thisArg[, arg1[, arg2[, ...]]])
```

Es decir, el primer elemento es el contexto (lo que será `this` en la función), y luego el resto de parámetros.

Asumiendo que la lista que tienes (NodeList) es el `arreglo` de tu ejemplo, puedes usarlo así:

```js
let lista = document.querySelectorAll('div');
console.log('¿Es un NodeList?',lista instanceof NodeList);
console.log('¿Tiene método slice?', lista.slice !== undefined);
let a = Array.prototype.slice.call(lista,0,3);
let b = Array.prototype.slice.call(lista,3);
console.log(a,b);


//otras formas de hacerlo
let miSliceFn = Array.prototype.slice.bind(lista); //asociamos el método a lista

console.log(miSliceFn(0,5));

//"Robamos el método"
lista.slice = Array.prototype.slice;

console.log(lista.slice(0,2));
```

```html
<div id="1"></div>
<div id="2"></div>
<div id="3"></div>
<div id="4"></div>
<div id="5"></div>
<div id="6"></div>
```

Comment: muchisimas gracias es justo lo que necesito!

Comment: Es una pregunta interesante y el "tomar prestadas funciones" es un tema que al principio es complicado

Answer (score 0):

La manera en que estás llamando a [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/slice) es incorrecta.

Por un lado, ya que tienes una variable de tipo arreglo, diría que no hace falta llamar a `Array.prototype.slice`. Yo llamaría directamente a `slice()` sobre el arreglo.

Luego, los parámetros que recibe `slice` son el inicio y el fin de la *tajada* que queremos sacar. En resumen, podrías hacer:

```js
let arreglo = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

let mitadArr1 = arreglo.slice(0, 5);
let mitadArr2 = arreglo.slice(5);

console.log(mitadArr1);
console.log(mitadArr2);
```

Comment: Ha puesto el concepto de lo que tiene, arreglo es un NodeList, no un Array

Comment: Pablo, tienes toda la razón, por un momento olvidé ese detalle y me centré en el código que veía. Gracias por la aclaración.